# Review my F# BubbleSort Program

Tags: functional-programming, sorting, f#

I have written this code for BubbleSort in F#. Can you review and let me know how I can do this in most functional way.

```
let rec getHighest list = 
    match list with
    | [x] -> x
    | [x; y] when x > y -> x 
    | [x; y] -> y
    | hd1 :: hd2 :: tl when hd1 > hd2 -> getHighest (hd1 :: tl)
    | hd1 :: tl -> getHighest tl
    | _ -> failwith "unknown pattern"

let bubbleSort list = 
    let rec innerBubbleSort sorted = function
    | [] -> sorted
    | l -> 
        let x = getHighest l
        let (a, b) = List.partition (fun i -> i = x) l
        innerBubbleSort (a @ sorted) b
    innerBubbleSort [] list

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    let input = [10; 7; 1; 0; -1; 9; 33; 12; 6; 2; 3; 33; 34;]
    let output = bubbleSort input
    printfn "%s" (List.fold (fun acc x -> acc + " " + x.ToString()) "" output)
    0
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part could be rewritten as

```
match list with
| hd1 :: hd2 :: tl when hd1 > hd2 -> getHighest (hd1 :: tl)
| hd1 :: hd2 :: tl -> getHighest (hd2::t1)
| hd1 :: [] -> hd1
| _ -> failwith "unknown pattern"
```

which is significantly simpler

Comment: even simpler if you replace the first two patterns with a single one: `| hd1::hd2::tl -> let hd = if hd1 > hd2 then hd1 else hd2 in getHighest (hd::tl)`

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner way to write `getHighest` would be to use accumulator:

```
let getHighest list =
    let rec getHighestImpl list highest =
        match list with
        | [] -> highest
        | head::tail -> getHighestImpl tail (max head highest)
    getHighestImpl (List.tail list) (List.head list)
```

You could also use the version of this function that already exists in the library: [`List.max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370242.aspx).

---

This is not bubble sort. In bubble sort, you compare neighboring items and swap them if they're in the wrong order. You do something similar in your `getHighest`, but you don't preserve the swaps. So, in the end, your algorithm is closer to [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_sort), than bubble sort.